# How to prevent X server from closing?

Tags: bash, java, raspberry-pi, xorg

I'm running a headless graphical application (kiosk) on a Raspberry Pi. So far so good: Raspbian autologins with the `pi` user and triggers `.bash_profile`, which in turns calls `startx` as long as I'm not logged through SSH, and `.xinitrc` takes care of launching the Java graphical app.

Problem arises when the app auto-updates. To modify it's own (opened) files, it creates a separate headless update process (with `nohup bash update_script.sh`), then exits. The update itself goes well, as the files are correct after updating. However, I cannot restart the app successfully at the end of the script, and I get:

> X11: Failed to open display :0

From what I understand, the X server shut down when the JVM process ended.

**How can I prevent the X server shutdown and piggyback on the session from inside my updater script?**

Keep in mind that I *need* to resort to `nohup` before calling the updater script, else the update would run in a child process of the original JVM, and would disappear with it when the app stops in order to release locks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I understand, the X server shut down when the JVM process ended.

The startx/xinit tool shuts down the X server when your .xinitrc script process ends.

> How can I prevent the X server shutdown

Launch something else from .xinitrc – traditionally one would start a window manager as the last process, since the window manager is expected to last the entire lifetime of the X session.

(Even full-screen apps might occassionally show pop-up windows, so a WM is still handy to have. I would probably use Openbox for this purpose.)

Alternatively, launch whatever you want that just never exits, such as `sleep infinity` or `sleep 9999d`. The point is that your .xinitrc script should never end.

> I'm running a headless graphical application (kiosk)

If it's a kiosk and has a display attached to show the graphical app, then it's not headless.

Comment: Perfect, it was as simple as that. I was worried that I would have trouble reconnecting to the existing display but everything went smoothly.
You're right for the "headless" part. I lacked the word to say it had no input devices.